# Creating schedule at 2 specific hours in a day

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need a schedule to run at 08:35 and 09:46 every day.

I now how to make a shedule that runs at some hours, it goes like this:

```
dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name        => 'YOUR_JOB',
                          job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
                          job_action      => 'integration_export;',
                          start_date      => systimestamp,
                          repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byhour=8,10,12,14,16,18; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
                      enabled         => true,
                      auto_drop       => false,
                      comments        => 'some comment about the job');
```

But if I add the clause `minutely` then it runs on all these hours at those minutes.
How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Put `start_date` as date itself with exact time, `08:45`. Use the date functions and format for that. Make two jobs, one for 8:45 other for 09:46.

`start_date = to_date(to_char(trunc(sysdate) <add your time part with proper format>`

Sorry, don't have database access to verify that. But, the logic is, start_date with only date part dynamically changing and keeping the time part constant should work.